# How to generate with runif() including min and max?

Tags: r

Accordingo to `?runif`, this function will not generate either of min or max bounds. How can I do something like `runif` but including min and max?

This is just for pure theory. I was wondering - what if I actually needed to randomly generate some values from uniform distribution, including the lower bound.

Comment: it's a bit of an odd question since (modulo some details of floating point accuracy) this restriction would only come into play a very small fraction of the time, conservatively once in every 10^8 draws ... Can you give a bit more context please?

Comment: e.g. `set.seed(101); sum(runif(1e7)<=.Machine$double.eps)` gives zero.

Comment: actually closer to `2/.Machine$integer.mx` = 1 in 10^9

Comment: @BenBolker This just purely theoretical question - no deep context.

Comment: From a purely theoretical point of view, it doesn't matter whether the min and max are included or not. Two points in a continuous interval form a subset of measure 0.

Comment: The code that eliminates the endpoints is in https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/runif.c , but it doesn't look like it's easy to access `unif_rand()` (the primitive function) from R ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own uniform distribution function that includes the endpoints using the `sample` function:

```
myrunif <- function(n, min=0, max=1) {
  min + (sample(.Machine$integer.max, n) - 1) / (.Machine$integer.max - 1) *
    (max - min)
}
```

With this function, each endpoint has a small probability, `1/(.Machine$integer.max-1)`, of being returned.

However, it's worthwhile remembering that mathematically the probability of drawing either a or b (or any particular value) from a U(a, b) random variable is 0, so the current behavior of `runif` makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

In pure theory the probability of any single value being generated from a continuous distribution will be 0, so the probability of min or max is 0.

From a practical standpoint if you really want to generate a uniform (which will round to a finite set of values and therefore having probability greater than 0 of being seen) with the possibility of seeing the desired min and max values, then just generate a uniform between min-epsilon and max+epsilon.  Now min and max are in the range and have a chance of being chosen just like the other values.  You just need to choose a value of epsilon such that values between min-epsilon and min will round to min and similar for the max.