# Generate Random Double while including Min Limit

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to generate a random double in R between 0 and 100, with 0 being a possible result, and normally `runif(1, min, max)` would do what I need. However, if I understand it correctly `runif` will only give you results between the min and max and never the actual limits.

Is there a way in R to generate a random double that includes only one of the limits? (In this case, 0≤x<100)

josliber created a custom function that includes both limits (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070116/6429759), but I'm afraid that I don't know if this can be modified to only include min.

I do realise this would only change the outcome an extremely small fraction of the time, but it's part of a function that will be run extremely frequently, so it's not for nothing.

Comment: the probability to have a precise number is zero in theory if you have a continuous distribution, even if you run it extremely frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring R for the moment, the probability of obtaining *exactly* 0 when sampling from the uniform distribution is 0 - so for all practical purposes, drawing from the open interval and the closed interval are essentially the same.

Now, in R (or any computer-based system, for that matter), we cannot actually represent an infinite number of numbers, because we're working with a finite representational system.  So you technically are drawing from a finite population, and there is a non-zero probability of drawing a boundary point.  However, a *good* random number generator (and R has several pretty good ones) will do a pretty good job of mimicking reality - which means that even if you drew from a closed interval instead of an open interval, the probability of actually drawing 0 is negligible.

Comment: this is more or less dealt with in one of the answers to the question linked by the OP.  If we suppose they're going to be running the function more than a billion times, the probability of drawing 0 at least once (from the appropriately discretized distribution) becomes non-negligible (although it's admittedly hard to see why it should matter ...)

Comment: `the probability of obtaining exactly 0 when sampling from the uniform distribution is 0` Nonsense! We're dealing with pseudoRNG, so probability to get 0 is about 1 in 4 billion (if your RNG generating integers in the range [0...2^32) )